# Table is not being created in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to Spring Boot and MySQL and I am trying to connect my spring boot application to the database I created in MySQL.
However when I run my code, the database is not being effected and no table is being added. I am not sure why. Please help.

application.properties class:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ems
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****

#hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.ddl-auto=update
```

pom.xml mysql dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Employee Model class:

```
package com.springboot.crud.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    

    
}
```

I am not sure what went wrong as I am new to all of this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly I am not allowed to comment. But I want to extend the answer given by @EXO_PJ.

While the answer is correct, it should be noted that this is not an option for a real productive stage of your application. Usually I tend to use the create option for local development only.

A more sophisticated solution would include the usage of an init script (e.g. to set up migration user and database settings) and a migration framework like "Flyway" or others to build up tables and stuff.